# Possible to test SQS -> Lambda -> API locally

Tags: lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue, when a message is published Lambda consumes it, transforms the data and then sends it to an API endpoint.

I'm looking to test this entire process locally. I have the API flask app running locally and also SQS queues running locally following https://campfirecode.medium.com/testing-aws-sqs-locally-in-python-a-guide-to-get-started-4c1be9792a6b

Is there a way to trigger the Lambda part locally?